# Run AsyncTask from another activity

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a button in my launcher activity which is menu.java and when I click said button I want it to load the other activity MainActivity.java and run the AsyncTask in said actvity without having to click another button.

This is my menu.java activity:

```
package davidgb.baseballspain;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Menu extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    Button beis = (Button) findViewById(R.id.beis);

    beis.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.beis:
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.doit.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            //new MainActivity.doit().execute();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }


}
}
```

The thing is when i click the button in the menu.java it loads the MainActivity but it doesn't run the AsyncTask directly, it just crashes. Im new to coding, any advice will be highly appreciate.

Edit: Fixed this by creating a new class and implementing the AsyncTask there.

Comment: `it just crashes`. what is your crash log?

Comment: call asynctask in oncreate of MainActivity..post your MainActivity code where it is crashing

Comment: Why you are starting two activities, is it in requirement?

Comment: Do you start Asynch task in oncreate()? Not just instantiate it, but EXECUTE it too?  And if it crashes, it might be that you want to use some variables / data from your previous activity in that AsyncTask .. which you might do incorrectly, so the App crashes due to NPE. But this are all guesses, cannot know without MainActivity class nor LogCat error.

Comment: The asynctask works just fine. Its inside a public class which i run with a button in the mainactivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you are calling the below

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.doit.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
break;
```

It considers that `MainActivity.doit.class` is also an Activity. While your Activity is `MainActivity`

Just put the below lines in your button click

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent1);
```

And call your `AsyncTask` inside the `MainActivity` `onCreate()` method like

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new doitTask().execute();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer this with the info provided. I think what you're trying to do is not possible or just really bad practice. I'm guessing the AsyncTask of the MainActivity is trying to communicate with the interface of the MainActivity, which it can't. Instead what you should do is start the AsyncTask in the onCreate of the MainActivity, and start it based on bundle extras and it shouldn't crash, or there is something wrong with the AsyncTask that you havn't provided.

Good luck!

Comment: Ok, I'll try that

Answer (score 1):

You have errors in your code.

1. Class name can't be like MainActivity.doit
2. There is no break in case statement. you are trying to start MainActivity activity and then MainActivity.doit
3. MainActivity.doit is not declared in manifest.

So rename MainActivity.doit to someother and declare in manifest and change the case statement to following.

```
case R.id.beis:
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent1);
        break;
```

Comment: Yes, I did. The activity loads fine, its the asynctask un the activity which doesnt load.

Comment: no your log cat says it clearly that u haven't declared the activity in manifest

Answer (score 1):

A lot of things in your code are fundamentally wrong... I'll try to cover the most important parts.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.doit.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

The above-mentioned code will assume the subclass `doit` to be an `Activity` and try to start it. The crash says there is no declaration of the `Activity` **MainActiviy.doit** in your `AndroidManfest.xml` file.

---

```
new MainActivity.doit().execute();
```

This code will create a new instance of the class `MainActivity` and execute its **doit** `AsyncTask`. This instance will not be the same as the `Activity` visible to the user, it is a completely different instance.

---

Handling this case correctly will highly depend on what exactly you are trying to do. If the **doit** has nothing to do with `MainActivity`, I would suggest moving it out in a separate class. If it has something to do very specific to `MainActivity`, you can pass in a few things in your `AsyncTask` as a parameter like:

```
new DoIt().execute(lblMyLabel);
```

Or you can keep it in the `MainActivity` as it is, but start it based on some `Extra` as suggested by @jobbert, if the `Activity` is not started already that is.

According to me, the best way would be to move out **doit** as a completely different class and pass in a listener (implementation of your own custom interface) and handle UI stuff with that in your `MainActivity`. Something like:

```
public class DoSomething {
    public static void doIt(final MyListener listener) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            public String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                return "Something is done here";
            }

            public void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                listener.onDone(result);
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    public interface MyListener {
        public void onDone(String result);
    }
}
```

And invoke it from your `MainActivity` or anywhere else like:

```
DoSomething.doIt(new DoSomething.MyListener() {
    Override
    public void onDone(String result) {
        lblHelloWorld.setText(result);
    } 
});
```